# Bounding the size of clique minor of the union of two graphs

Tags: graph-minors

Suppose that graphs $A$ and $B$ with $V(A)=V(B)$ have Hadwiger numbers $a$ and $b$. That is, $K_a$ and $K_b$ are the largest clique minors of $A$ and $B$, respectively.
Are there upper bounds on the Hadwiger number of the union graph $A\cup B$ (with edge set $E(A\cup B)=E(A)\cup E(B)$) using $a$ and $b$ like $a+b$ or $a\cdot b$?

Comment: What is the union graph? $A$, $B$ are the graphs on the same ground set $V$, and we take the union of their edge sets?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, yes. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a complete graph $G_n$, replace each edge $uv$ to a path $uxv$. Imagine that $ux\in A$, $vx\in B$, and that's for every edge. It looks that both $A,B$ are forests, so have small Hadwiger number.